Why can’t I connect to an SSH server on Windows?
I'm trying to connect to my PC from my laptop when I'm out of town. First I made sure my VPN was turned off. I live in Egypt and my ISP is WE Egypt (aka: Telecom Egypt).
I set everything up but it's not working.
Here's what I did and where it all went wrong:

Installed the OpenSSH server from the optional features.
Added the public key of my friend to the authorized_keys file
I Got my IP address from here https://whatismyipaddress.com/ I got (the IP address).
On my friend's laptop we ran ssh pc@(the IP address)

And finally, I have this set up on my router:



Enable
Name
WAN Host Start IP Address
WAN Start Port
LAN Host Start Port
WAN Connection
Modify
Delete
Protocol
WAN Host End IP Address
WAN End Port
LAN Host End Port
LAN Host Address





SSH Server

22
22
PVC0


TCP

22
22
192.168.1.2



Here's where it all goes wrong, i get this
ssh: connect to host (the IP address) port 22: Connection refused
I went on to try anything I found online and nothing worked
Here's what I tried:

Add out and in allow on my Windows firewall on port 22.
Checked the SSH config to be specific to the port and it was 22.
I tried to run ssh pc@(the IP address) from the same PC that has the server and I got the same response.

So my question is, what am I missing or what should I check next?

Update: I contacted my ISP about this and i got this reponse

"Dear Mr/George ,
Thank you for contacting WE Customer Care team. Kindly accept our apologies for any inconveniences , and regarding your below mentioned request , be noted that you must opt in optionpack to access your PC , and opt in optionpack is not available for now.
Best regards
We Customer Care"

Does that end it or there or is there something I can do about this without the optionpack?

Are you behind a CGNAT? If you truly used a IP address that could be reached from your friend’s iSP to your ISP then you would not have received the error you received. Connect the laptop to the same network as your server and connect to 192.168.1.2

to determine if you are behind CGNAT, check if your public IP is in the 100.64.0.0/10 range

After installing the server did you start it? Check sc queryex sshd or ps get-service sshd and netstat -an | findstr LISTEN or ps get-nettcpconnection -state listen to make sure it is actually listening on port 22 and address 'all' (zeros or double colon)

I'd guess that the "optionpack" is a 'real'/routable IP address and that's not offered yet.
